# Show that for any pair of primes $p$, $q$ the group $(\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/q \Bbb Z, +)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/pq\Bbb Z, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Show that for any pair of primes $p$, $q$ the group $(\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/q \Bbb Z, +)$ is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/pq\Bbb Z, +)$

I’m having trouble solving this problem. I solved what seems to me to be a nearly identical problem,

> Show that if $n$ and $m$ are not co-prime then $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is never isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/nm \Bbb Z$.

I solved this by contraposition, demonstrating a mapping, showing homomorphism and bijection and then applying the Chinese remainder theorem. How does the addition of “component wise addition” change the approach? Or does it? Is the same approach I used for the quoted problem above a valid one. I guess I’m struggling to understand what the group implication means for the problem statement in the title. Isn’t the quotient group modulo $\Bbb Z$ already additive? Why does $(\ , +)$ make a difference? I've been in abstract algebra for six weeks so please excuse any errors in logic or misuse of terminology.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Also, please consider using paragraphs.

Comment: The $(\cdot, +)$ notation is just there to emphasize that the group operation is the usual one. (I guess the other immediate alternative would be integer multiplication, but that obviously doesn't give you a group.)

Comment: The problem should specify $p\neq q$; if this is not specified, then nothing prevents you from picking the same prime twice, in which case the claimed isomorphism does not hold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**  $\varphi :\Bbb Z_{pq}\to\Bbb Z_p\oplus \Bbb Z_q$ given by $\varphi (1)=(1,1)$ can be verified to determine an isomorphism.

The inverse is $\varphi ^{-1}(x,y)=apx+bqy$, where $a$ and $b$ are such that $ap+bq=1$.

---

(Incidentally, this works if we replace $p,q$ by relatively prime $m,n$.

This is essentially the *Chinese remainder theorem* (though actually about rings):   $\exists! z\in \Bbb Z_{mn} $ such that $z\cong x\pmod m$ and $z\cong y\pmod n$.

This also establishes the multiplicativity of Euler's totient function, $\phi$, which counts the numbers less than $n$ relatively prime to $n$.  Namely, $\phi(mn)=\phi(m)\phi(n)$.)